# Copying Outlook email body to .csv

Tags: vba, csv, outlook, outlook-2010

After running the code, I am getting **run-time Error 9 ( subscript out of range )**.

I am getting the error on this line :

```
xlSheet.Range("K" & rCount) = Trim(varItem(1))
```

I looked through the code and I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong or missing.

Here is code & see below what my email body looks like

```
            '// Customer
            If InStr(1, varText(i), "Customer") > 0 Then
                varItem = Split(varText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = Trim(varItem(1))
            End If


            '// Service Level
            If InStr(1, varText(i), "Service Level") > 0 Then
                varItem = Split(varText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("K" & rCount) = Trim(varItem(1))
            End If
```

[image]

Comment: What line does the error come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch the **`Chr(58))`** to **`Chr(9))'    horizontal tab`**

```
varItem = Split(varText(i), Chr(9))
```

Look at  VBA [[Chr]](http://www.techonthenet.com/ascii/chart.php)

Answer (score 1):

For a `Split` result, I generally do this :

```
Dim varItem() As String

varItem = Split(varText(i), Chr(58))
```

Which might help as `Trim()` is a text function.

After that, best guess is that there is no `Chr(58) = ":"` in `varText(i)` and therefore, `varItem(1)` would be out of range. Try with `varItem(0)` just to see if it works, or use a `MsgBox InStr(1,varText(i), Chr(58))`.

Comment: I think you maybe right on `Chr(58) = " : "`  the code works on  when `varText`  is `Name: Name` will let you know once I am done thanks @R3uK + 1

Comment: Yup, not sure what you can use as a seperator here, try to compile Asc() of your individuals characters between "header" and information, so that you know which one you can use